# Creating a search query using JSON news api

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jquery-mobile

So I got to create a search query based on an written javascript file (below) and I also have to use this URL to create the search query. At the end of the URL, you can add any search term you like. For example, we will search about food : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=food
Can anyone tell me what to do to create it?

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(ev){
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $.get('search.php', {"q": $('#search').val()}, function(data){
            var json = JSON.parse(data);                
            console.log(json);








            $('#results').listview('refresh');  
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the search.php returning. And why are you using a php call. you can access the json from the api direct with javascript

Comment: @Ridrog that were the given code by my tutor, i have no idea >.<!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**
You can access this api direct with javascript (jquery).

If you try it with the normal url `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=food` you get an error because of the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Settings.
If you append "&callback=?" you will get proper data returned

Now you have to append the returned data to your listview.

The important thing to know is: what is returned. In your code the value of `data` or the value of `var json` Since you dont provide any of your php. i can only do it direct with the jquery getJSON Call.

```js
 $(document).bind('pageinit', function(ev) {
   $('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {

       // The Base URL
       var baseUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=';

       // The question from the inputfield
       var q = $('#search').val();

       // putting the url togehter and append &callback=?
       var url = baseUrl + q + "&callback=?";
       console.log(url);

       // Call The API for a JSON
       $.getJSON(url, function() {
         console.log("success");
       }).done(function(data) {
         console.log("second success");

         console.log(data.responseData.results);

         // create a var for the results and append a header
         var results = '<li data-role="list-divider">Results</li>';

         $.each(data.responseData.results, function(index, item) {

           results += '<li>';
           results += item.title;
           results += '</li>';
         });



         // clear the results . append the results .refresh the listview
         $('#results').empty().append(results).listview('refresh');

       }).fail(function() {
         console.log("error");
       }).always(function() {
         console.log("always");
       });



     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<!-- page1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-title="page1">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /Header -->

  <!-- Content -->
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">

    <label for="search">Search Input:</label>
    <input name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="palceholder" type="search">

    <ul data-role="listview" id="results" data-inset="true">

    </ul>

    <script>
    </script>

  </div>
  <!-- /Content -->

</div>
<!-- /page1 -->
```

Comment: the code snippet is only working with a firefox browser. Chrome, Opera and IE only shows a loading animation.

Comment: At the end it doesnt matter which data you use. You can also use the returned and paresd json from your php call. You only need to figure out the structure of the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).bind('pageinit', function(ev) {
   $('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {

       // The Base URL
       var baseUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=';

       // The question from the inputfield
       var q = $('#search').val();

       // putting the url togehter and append &callback=?
       var url = baseUrl + q + "&callback=?";
       console.log(url);

       // Call The API for a JSON
       $.getJSON(url, function() {
         console.log("success");
       }).done(function(data) {
         console.log("second success");

         console.log(data.responseData.results);

         // create a var for the results and append a header
         var results = '<li data-role="list-divider">Results</li>';

         $.each(data.responseData.results, function(index, item) {

           results += '<li>';
           results += item.title;
           results += '</li>';
         });



         // clear the results . append the results .refresh the listview
         $('#results').empty().append(results).listview('refresh');

       }).fail(function() {
         console.log("error");
       }).always(function() {
         console.log("always");
       });



     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<!-- page1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-title="page1">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /Header -->

  <!-- Content -->
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">

    <label for="search">Search Input:</label>
    <input name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="palceholder" type="search">

    <ul data-role="listview" id="results" data-inset="true">

    </ul>

    <script>
    </script>

  </div>
  <!-- /Content -->

</div>
<!-- /page1 -->
```